# asp.net mvc regular expression

Tags: asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc

```
(@"^\w+(?: \w+){0,8}$"
```

the above regular expression restrict all the special characters except _ . how would i restrict it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
@"^[^\W_]+(?: [^\W_]+){0,8}$"
```

to allow everything that `\w` matches except `_`.

`\W` means "any character that isn't matched by `\w`", so by putting it into a negated character class and adding a `_` to that class, we're effectively subtracting `_` from `\w`.*

In other words, `[^\W_]` means "match any character that is neither a non-alphanumeric character nor an underscore".

Another way (perhaps more explicit and easier to understand) would be to use Unicode properties:

```
@"^[\p{L}\p{N}]+(?: [\p{L}\p{N}]+){0,8}$"
```

where `[\p{L}\p{N}]` means "any Unicode letter or number".

---

*In .NET, the `\w` shorthand matches a lot more than `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, especially international (non-ASCII) letters.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `\w` with `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. The shortcut `\w` matches any word character, i.e., alphanumeric characters and the underscore.

```
@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?: [a-zA-Z0-9]+){0,8}$"
```

You can use `[a-z0-9]` once you figure out how to set the `i` flag (case-insensitive) on.